# Detecting webhost server

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have a web app that is using the 3.5 framework. I wanted to know how can I detect what webhost is rendering the page.

If the server is localhost, then send email notification to test@dev.com
If the server is QA, then send email to xyz@dev.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean to do this detection server-side, then how about the old-fashioned ServerVariables ?

```
string serverName = Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"];
string httpHost = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
```

A full list of server variables is here: http://www.aspcode.net/List-of-RequestServerVariables.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The closest your probably going to get with what you want is the machine name:

```
System.Environment.MachineName
```

localhost is an address, and every machine can access itself through it (assuming someone didn't monkey with the hosts file).

You could get the URL accessing the page: `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`.  This will tell you most likely what environment they are trying to hit (except if they use local host to access the site).

> If the server is localhost, then send
>   email notification to test@dev.com If
>   the server is QA, then send email to
>   xyz@dev.com

If you have access to the machine config, an easier way might be to place the email address in the [appsettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) you want to send emails to there.  That way you can vary it by environment and not worry about what machine/url they are trying to hit.

Comment: where in machine.config would I add the email addr?

Comment: you can place it in the appsettings portion and access the key by name.

Answer (score 1):

The [System.Web.HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) class has an [IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) property that tells you exactly this.  It is a little more robust than using the server variables, as it checks for things like "127.0.0.1".

Comment: interesting catch. I will look into it. Thanks Josh !!